# Office Excel 2016 update not applying.

Tags: ms-office

My current Excel version is 15.26.0. Available is v15.34.0.

Via the Check for Updates (Menu option), and with the update software itself updated, I have downloaded this update 3 times.

The installation process is indicated that it has been installed and updated. However the update software does another check and indicates this update is still needed (as if it was not done). A laptop restart and check confirms that the Excel version is still 15.26.0.

Any thoughts on why the update is not sticking.

Answer (score 1):

Cause was my previous renaming of the Excel application in the application folder.

In the application folder I had previously added the suffice 2016 to the name of the Excel program to delineate it from the older version (kept in event of compatibility issues with old files) from the 2011 suite.

The download process added the update application separately with its original name "Microsoft Excel.app"  Deleting the old version, adding the prefix 2016 (as is my preference) to the new Excel file. Open this, and all works with the right version.

So as tidy up, deleting the old icon first from the doc, then copying Excel with its appended name afresh to the Dock, and now all works and opens as version 15.34.0

Comment: I am aware that officially from Microsoft, excel files saved or created in Excel 2016 should still be fully compatible in Excel 2011. So far I have found this to be true. And with Excel 2016 more stable then 2011. However, I keep the 2011 version just in case.